# strange behavior php.ini allow_url_fopen

Tags: php, cpanel, fopen

I have a godaddy shared hosting (ultimate package) with cpanel installed.

In my **public_html** folder i have a **php.ini** file that before has:

```
allow_url_fopen = off
```

Now i ve changed on:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

When i check with phpinfo() function sometimes the allow_url_fopen is ON and sometimes is OFF (by refreshing the page)

i really don't understand why this happen!!!

PS: i don't think i need/can reboot with cpanel

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the http server after having altered the php configuration.

Most likely the different output results from different http child processes. Some have already been restarted (spawned), some not yet. Therefor they use a different configuration.

Restarting the http server should make sure *all* children are restarted as soon as possible or *now*, depending on *how* you restart the server.

Note that for restarting the http server you do *not* need to reboot. You just need to restart that server. How you do that depends on the distribution you are using. Probably something like:

```
rcapache2 graceful
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/httpd graceful
```